# Swift Nested array object POST with Alamofire Error

Tags: arrays, swift, post, alamofire

I have this code:

```
var painBody: [PutPainBody]? = nil
    
    if let pains = physicalConditionData.pains {
        painBody = []
        for pain in pains {
            let painData = PutPainBody(
                provoking_factor: pain.provokingFactor,
            )
            painBody?.append(painData)
        }
    }
```

then body API parameter:

```
var body = PutAssessmentPhysicalConditionBody(
        form_name: AssessementFormName.PHYSICAL_CONDITION.rawValue,
        pains: painBody
}
```

after that, I put it in the config here to send with Alamofire:

```
let config = PutAssessmentCaseFormAPI(caseId: caseId, parameters: body.dictionary)
    self.remoteDS.request(config, model: PhysicalConditionModel.self) { resp in
// usual API post with Alamofire
```

then here's the code for the .dictionary encoder:

```
extension Encodable {
public var dictionary: [String: Any] {
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return [String: Any]() }

    let requestStr  = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)! as String
    
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] } ?? [String: Any]()
    }
}
```

BUT, it always give me error. I'm SURE 100% that the problem is within the painBody because when I change variable pains: painBody to pains: [], then it will give no error! I suspect that I have to encode each of value inside of painBody array, I have tried that too with .dictionary code that I built but it still gave me error (maybe my way to encode each of the value is wrong?). Can anyone help how to solve this? I have worked on this for a long time and still not found the solution..

The error: No data error!
So the response.data and response.result both are nill. But strange enough, other variables value in PutAssessmentPhysicalConditionBody change even I receive this no data error! It's just the pains that is still doesn't change

Comment: If you already have an `Encodable` type there's no need to convert it to a dictionary. And by ignoring errors you may post an empty body unexpectedly. So get rid of that and just use the normal Alamofire `Encodable` request methods. Oh, and no one can really help unless you actually post the error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks @JonShier for ur suggestion, I have added the error, I am just soo confused with this. Other variable value is changed but gave an error of response.result and response.data nil, and just this pains variable that doesn't change!

Comment: And for another put API with data type like string, int, double, this code works just fine. Just with this custom object array that give me this error...

Comment: You'll want to inspect your full response (`debugPrint(response)`) to see what's going on. You'll also want to check your server documentation to see what it says for body formats and how it'll respond in certain scenarios. It may be that posting up new data just gets a 200, in which case Alamofire will produce an error because a 200 with no body data isn't technically correct. There are various answers here for enabling other status codes with empty bodies.